# How to remove children from tree node list

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have list of tree nodes. lets say (a b c d). b node is a parent of some e node and e is a parent of c. I want to write algorithm to remove nodes like c from list.

Any suggestions except iterating over all parents of each node and comparing with each element?

Comment: Have a list or array of the nodes you have already been at, and break the link when you run into a node that you already visited?

Comment: you want to remove the leaf nodes?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to remove the hole list? just one node?